# jest instace().simulate('dayClick'); TypeError does not exist

Tags: reactjs, sinon, jestjs, react-day-picker

I have a component that is using `'react-day-picker'`.

This component has a method called `handleDayClick`:

```
handleDayClick(e, day, {disabled}) {
        if (disabled) {
            // Do not update the state if the day is disabled
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ selectedDay: day });
        this.props.dateClick(day);
    };
```

It is then passed to the  as the onDayClick prop:

```
<DayPicker
   onDayClick={ this.handleDayClick.bind(this) }
   selectedDays={ day => DateUtils.isSameDay(day, this.state.selectedDay) }
   disabledDays={ isWeekend }
 />
```

Now I would like to write a test that simulates a click event on a date to see if it triggers the correct method:

```
it('DayPicker should call handleDayClick on click', () => {
    const sidebar = mount(<Sidebar />);
    let spy = sinon.spy(sidebar.instance(), 'handleDayClick');
    sidebar.update();
    sidebar.find(DayPicker).simulate('dayClick');
    expect(spy.called).toBe(true);
  });
```

The problem with this is that the [.simulate()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html) does not recognize `'dayClick'`. I get the following error in the console:

> TypeError: ReactWrapper::simulate() event 'dayClick' does not exist

If I try to simulate `'click'` instead, the spy returns `false` (so the method is never called).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simulate only supports events that React understands

(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#simulate)

This is why you're getting your error on dayClick.

To simulate the click you should dive into react-day-picker and find out what DOM element the onClick prop eventually gets assigned to. Then simulate the click on that.

---

Edit - This is the component that contains the DOM node that gets the click handler

https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/blob/master/src/Day.js

You should look to simulate the test on the `<div>` inside the `Day` component

Comment: Correct, the div class is .DayPicker-Day for the enabled divs. So: sidebar.find('.DayPicker-Day').first().simulate('click'); solved the issue.

Thanks